# Python script to parse URLs and extract usernames & passwords in a text file

Tags: python, regex, url

I was wondering if you could please help me with this simple request. I did search for an existing solution, but I couldn't figure this out because I am not an expert.
I need usernames and passwords extracted. I will have a txt file with URLs.
I'd like a python script to read the file, parse each URL and extract the `username:password` in a new text file. The url could `.org`, `.net`, `.com`, etc.

```
http://URL:8080/get.php?username=C59VGdbeJn&password=rNWotM0B6Z&type=list
http://URL:80/get.php?username=D7mPSv9mK6&password=wboR54rDft&type=list
http://URL:80/get.php?username=K8TpaFNvSD&password=3DYIRewM07&type=list
http://URL:8443/get.php?username=KR2gCmAHkq&password=sbhfT2D0B2&type=list
http://URL:80/get.php?username=LA5f3EpWVy&password=oegihMj2mV&type=list
http://URL:80/get.php?username=NHzr2qHgzyDP&password=I9nRDgT5ZK&type=list
```

The text file output would contain:

```
C59VGdbeJn:rNWotM0B6Z
D7mPSv9mK6:wboR54rDft
K8TpaFNvSD:DYIRewM07
KR2gCmAHkq:sbhfT2D0B2
LA5f3EpWVy:oegihMj2mV
NHzr2qHgzyDP:I9nRDgT5ZK
```

Thanks, Folks.

Have a great day!

I did search for an existing solution, but I couldn't figure this out because I am not an expert.

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your current code in the question, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the URLs in an `input_file.txt` file:

```
http://URL:8080/get.php?username=C59VGdbeJn&password=rNWotM0B6Z&type=list
http://URL:80/get.php?username=D7mPSv9mK6&password=wboR54rDft&type=list
http://URL:80/get.php?username=K8TpaFNvSD&password=3DYIRewM07&type=list
http://URL:8443/get.php?username=KR2gCmAHkq&password=sbhfT2D0B2&type=list
http://URL:80/get.php?username=LA5f3EpWVy&password=oegihMj2mV&type=list
http://URL:80/get.php?username=NHzr2qHgzyDP&password=I9nRDgT5ZK&type=list
```

You can try this:

```
import re
output_list = []
with open('input_file.txt') as f:
    for url in f.readlines():
        data = re.search(r'username=(.+)&password=(.+)&', url)
        output_list.append(f"{data.group(1)}:{data.group(2)}\n")

with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(output_list)
```

You will get the `output_file.txt` file:

```
C59VGdbeJn:rNWotM0B6Z
D7mPSv9mK6:wboR54rDft
K8TpaFNvSD:3DYIRewM07
KR2gCmAHkq:sbhfT2D0B2
LA5f3EpWVy:oegihMj2mV
NHzr2qHgzyDP:I9nRDgT5ZK
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please mark it as a solution if it does help you :

```
import re

# Input and output file paths
input_file = "urls.txt"
output_file = "usernames_passwords.txt"

# Regular expression to match username and password
regex = r"username=([^&]*)&password=([^&]*)"

# Open input and output files
with open(input_file, "r") as f_in, open(output_file, "w") as f_out:
    # Loop over each line in the input file
    for line in f_in:
        # Extract the username and password using regex
        match = re.search(regex, line)
        if match:
            username = match.group(1)
            password = match.group(2)
            # Write the username:password to the output file
            f_out.write(f"{username}:{password}\n")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Given your input, say it is stored as a file located at '/path/to/inputfile'

And you want a file located at '/path/to/outputfile' to contain your desired output.

You can use this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

Path('/path/to/outputfile').write_text(
    '\n'.join(f'{a}:{b}'
        for a, b in re.findall(
            r'username=(\w+)&password=(\w+)&',
            Path('/path/to/inputfile').read_text()
        )
    )
)
```

Using `re.findall` will find all matches in one go, thus avoids repeatedly calling `re.search` unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the **`username`** and **`password`** from the URL string using Python's built-in **`urlparse`** module.

Here's an example code snippet that reads the `content.txt` file and extracts the `username` and `password` from each line:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

output_file = 'output_file.txt'

with open('content.txt') as f, open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in f:
        url = urlparse(line.strip())
        params = parse_qs(url.query)
        username = params['username'][0]
        password = params['password'][0]
        outfile.write(f"{username}:{password}\n")
```